# Dynamically set xsl stylesheet to an xsql file

Tags: xml, xslt, xsql

I want to set the xsl stylesheet to an xml file from the url (for example: index.xsql?style=html_style), now i'm using the following code:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="{@style}.xsl"?>`

My question is how can i set a default value to the style attribute? So when i simply use index.xsql without parameters, it should set a default value to style.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is too late, but what we did to solve a similar problem (in our case we needed different stylesheets depending on the type of content we wanted to produce, with html as the default) was to create a custom action handler for the purpose. This worked well. I can give you more information if you like.

Chris